# How confirm FTP upload in PowerShell using Putty

Tags: powershell, putty

I have a PowerShell script to upload a file to a FTP server. Everything is working OK.

```
$program = "C:\Putty\psftp.exe"
$pass = "test"
$hst = "109.18.205.14"
$user = "admin"
$file = "d:\FTP\Test.txt"
$cmd = @(
"cd /Test",
"put $file",
"bye"
)
[String]($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst" 2>&1)
```

My problem is that I need to confirm that the upload is successful or not. I just need an output message that says "Successful" or "Failed" , any idea?

Comment: Could you do a `Get $file` after the "upload"?

Comment: You could do a `dir` command as well and check the output

Comment: I can check it and the file is been copied. the thing is I want to send an email later with the content of "Success" or " failed" . but for now I need the system to give me a feedback of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to integrate this into your own code. I just added a `dir` command into your list. I'm not sure if it might be wise to do this as a separate session or not. Leaving your other variables alone i just added this to the end.

```
$cmd = @(
"cd /Test",
"put $file",
"dir",
"bye"
)
$return = @()
($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst") | ForEach-Object{$return+=$_}
If($return -match (Split-Path  $file -Leaf)){Write-Host "Success"} Else {Write-Host "Failed"}
```

In production i am not sure how this will work. Simply removing the `put` line in `$cmd` this does function a file checked. *Note* I though i could just do something like `$return = ($cmd | & $program -pw $pass "$user@$hst" -P 49000)` but somehow the psftp command kepy failing which is why i piped the output into and array called `$return`

Comment: I tested it and unfortunately it wont work :( first it pauses and then gives me a network timeout message.

Comment: What powershell version do you have?

Comment: What if you run this code separate to your `put` code. Take what i have and just remove the `put $file,` line. Copy my section after yours. Not replacing but adding?

Comment: Same result, Time out message again

Comment: Im sorry... i have a port designation in there from my testing. Remove the `-P 49000` if you copied my code that would be in there. I editied my post.

Comment: Its working, the problem was that it was trying to compare D:\FTP\Test.txt to Test.txt. Thank you buddy :)

Comment: Good catch i will update my answer. You can use `Split-Path  $file -Leaf` to get the file name

Answer (score 0):

if can you test-path to see if the file created exists.

If it exists, it will return true

something like this:

```
if(test-path $file){
  echo success;
}
Else{
  echo false;
}
```

Comment: This file will exist on a secure remote host that OP will not be able to test like that. The local copy $file would already exist so in theory this should always be true.

Comment: @Matt  Good point. If this is for personal use OP can get this http://www.netcmdlets.com/netcmdlets-file-transfer-ftp-and-sftp/ cmdlet. Then OP will be able to use get-ftp to do the same thing in one line.

Comment: Matt is right , I tested it and the output is always "Success"

Comment: @Arun This is the production.

Comment: @AliShariaty Try this, it can also list item: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb

Comment: @Arun I installed it, It does has the list item ( My putty does too) but how does it solve my problem?